# How to get same attribute values of a node, in a sequence using Xquery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

> Hi..I would like to print attribute values in a sequence ,for example If have an XML which looks like below

```
<module>
<content>
<catalouge SC="25" item="200">
<Number id="250" >
<Character condValue="PRE" changeMark="1">
<count Number="1" </count>
</Character>
<Character condValue="EMB">
<count Number="154"</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</catalouge>
<catalouge SC="25" item="200" >
<Number id="780">
<Character condValue="EMB" changeMark="1">
<count Number="1" </count>
</Character>
<Character condValue="EMB">
<count Number="154"</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</catalouge>
<catalouge SC="25" item="240">
<Number id="666" Value="123" >
<Character condValue="EMB">
<count Number="2" </count>
</Character>
</Number>
</catalouge>
<catalouge SC="25" item="280">
<Number id="1994" Value="1234" >
<Character condValue="POST">
<count Number="3"</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</catalouge>
<catalouge SC="25" item="300">
<Number id="19956" Value="1235">
<Character condValue="PRE">
<count Number="4" </count>
</Character>
</Number>
</catalouge>
</content>
</module>
```

> Please find below xquery which i have tried

```
for  $p in doc("abc.xml")//module/content
    let $csns := $p/catalouge
        for $csn in $csns
            let $item := $csn/string(@item)
            let $isns := $csn/Number
            for $isn in $isns
              let $id := $isn/string(@id)
              let $chr := $isn/Character/string(@condValue)
        return $chr
```

**Output:**
When I ran, I got output as below from above Xquery

PRE
EMB
EMB
EMB
EMB
POST
PRE

But I need in this way, How can I achieve below

```
("PRE","EMB")  
("EMB","EMB")  
"EMB"  
"POST"  
"PRE"
```

Comment: You have managed to use three nested `for` expressions, so just play with that approach to use `for` over the right nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
for $number in $doc//catalouge//Number
return string-join($number//Character//@condValue,", ")
```

Output:

```
PRE, EMB
EMB, EMB
EMB
POST
PRE
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) @Jack Fleeting , this worked , I'm new to xquery , I've tried string-join but somewhere I missed it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112178/xpty0004-item-expected-sequence-found-how-to-find-whether-a-value-is-present-i

Could you help me with this also please?

Comment: @Sreekala I'll take a look.