# XPTY0004 Item expected, sequence found, How to find whether a value is present in a sequence or not using Xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

> Hi.. I would like to find whether a value is present in a sequence or not ,for example If I have an XML which looks like below

```
<module>
<content>
<customer SC="25" item="200">
<Number id="250">
<Character Value="PRE" Evaluate="1">
<count Number="1" Name="Sree">FOR XYZ 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
</Character>
<Character Value="EMB">
<count Number="154" Name="Sree" Evaluate="1">FOR XYZ 1995, 1996, 1994, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</customer>
<customer SC="25" item="200" >
<Number id="780" >
<Character Value="EMB" Evaluate="1">
<count Number="1" Name="Sree">FOR XYZ 1998, 1995, 1996, 1994, 0357, 0376</count>
</Character>
<Character Value="EMB">
<count Number="154" Name="Sree" Evaluate="1">FOR XYZ 0357, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1994, 0376</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</customer>
<customer SC="25" item="240">
<Number id="666" Value="123" >
<Character Value="EMB">
<count Number="2" Name="Sree" Evaluate="1">FOR XYZ 1995, 1994, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</customer>
<customer SC="25" item="280">
<Number id="1994" Value="1234" >
<Character Value="POST">
<count Number="3" Name="Sree" Evaluate="1">FOR XYZ 1994, 1995, 1909, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</customer>
<customer SC="25" item="300">
<Number id="19956" Value="1235" >
<Character Value="PRE">
<count Number="4" Name="Sree" Evaluate="1">FOR XYZ 1997, 1995, 1996, 1994, 0357, 0376</count>
</Character>
</Number>
</customer>
</content>
</module>
```

> Please find below xquery

```
    for  $p in doc("abc.xml")//module/content
    let $csns := $p/catalouge
        for $csn in $csns
            let $item := $csn/string(@item)
            let $isns := $csn/Number
            for $isn in $isns
              let $id := $isn/string(@id)
      let $count :=  $isn/Character/data(count)
      let $count_status := contains($count, '1994')
return $count_status
```

> am trying to check whether count tag has a value **1994** (FOR A/C **1994**, 1995, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376) which returns boolean value
> While running Xquery I have tried with contains function but in vain, I got an error when i ran above Xquery

**Error:**
[XPTY0004] Item expected, sequence found: ("FOR A/C 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376", ...).

But I need to return a boolean value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XQuery. I tested it in BaseX 9.4.6

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare variable $year as xs:string :='1994';

declare context item := document {
<module>
    <content>
        <catalouge SC="25" item="200">
            <Number id="250" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="PRE" changeMark="1">
                    <count Number="1" Name="Sree">FOR A/C 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
                </Character>
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="154" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 1995, 1996, 1994, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="25" item="200">
            <Number id="780" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="EMB" changeMark="1">
                    <count Number="1" Name="Sree">FOR A/C 1998, 1995, 1996, 1994, 0357, 0376</count>
                </Character>
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="154" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 0357, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1994, 0376</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="25" item="240">
            <Number id="666" Value="123" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="EMB">
                    <count Number="2" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 1995, 1994, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="25" item="280">
            <Number id="1994" Value="1234" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="POST">
                    <count Number="3" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 1994, 1995, 1909, 1997, 0357, 0376</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
        <catalouge SC="25" item="300">
            <Number id="19956" Value="1235" RefIds="xyz20000">
                <Character condValue="PRE">
                    <count Number="4" Name="Sree" changeMark="1">FOR A/C 1997, 1995, 1996, 1994, 0357, 0376</count>
                </Character>
            </Number>
        </catalouge>
    </content>
</module>
};

<root>
{
  for $x in ./module/content/catalouge/Number/Character/count
  return <r status='{contains($x/text(), $year)}'>{data($x)}</r>
}
</root>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376</r>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 1995, 1996, 1994, 1997, 0357, 0376</r>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 1998, 1995, 1996, 1994, 0357, 0376</r>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 0357, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1994, 0376</r>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 1995, 1994, 1996, 1997, 0357, 0376</r>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 1994, 1995, 1909, 1997, 0357, 0376</r>
  <r status="true">FOR A/C 1997, 1995, 1996, 1994, 0357, 0376</r>
</root>
```